# Registering for notification emails from cloud-proactive-comms

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

My colleagues receive emails from "cloud-proactive-comms" with notifications to upgrade our cluster in response to security threats and stuff like that.

**How do I register for these emails as well?**

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to be a project owner in order to receive those emails form "cloud-proactive-comms".

You can also check with your colleague, which permission you are lacking to get those email. As it's possible that your colleague is a Project Owner.

Additionally, if you need RSS feeds available for Security bulletins related to Kubernetes Engine, please visit this [article](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/security-bulletins).